# How does `bne` know which bit field in the condition register to branch on? (PowerPC Gekko)

Tags: powerpc

I'm currently reversing a PowerPC Gekko program and saw a `bne` instruction that branched on the condition register after a `rlwinm` function. Perfect. That makes sense. `bne` is checking the third bit of the `CR0` bit field in the condition register. I assumed checking `CR0` was default and that made sense.

In the next few lines, there was another `bne` instruction that followed a `cmplwi` instruction. Cool, I can probably guess that we're branching after the `cmplwi` (I'm pretty sure this is a loop, probably a for loop). However, my documentation seems to say that `cmplwi` modifies the `CR3` bit field in the condition register.

Both instances of `bne` did not have a `CRx` argument as I saw in my documentation, so I'm lost as to which bit field it's checking.

Which bit field in the condition register does `bne` check when the condition register is unspecified?

Comment: You should better include the two assembler sections about the different bne usage in your question.

Comment: @Robert I'm confused by what your comment means.

Comment: I was talking aboutthe assembler instructions you are looking ate in IDA or whatever decompiler you have used. It would be easier to understand if you would copy the code sections you are talking about into your question.